# Onenote development

Tags: c#, .net, windows, onenote

I realize this is a very generic question, but struggling to find anything from Google. im just curious to find out if anyone has carried out any onenote API development. We have carried out some investigation, with no luck at the moment
Basically: - 
within a hospital,  we would like to create a windows application or website, where a consultant searches for a patient ( connecting to our internal database). 
The consultant can then select an option to create a onenote, which could either open onenote in a separate application, or within the custom application.

Consultant can then create a clinical note ( we're thinking surface pro with the hand writing ) and save. This would then attach the onenote to the patient which has been selected ( either as a onenote or as a pdf. )

Thinking this could be saved on a shared drive, and a link to the document in the database?

Is this possible within OneNote? What functionality would I be using?

Comment: I would not go OneNote API in this project because of the privacy issues of having to save the patient's information in the cloud. Go for an add-in. Otherwise, everything you asked is possible.

Comment: @hector thanks for this, when you say an add-in,  do you mean a onenote add-in?

Comment: Yes. I am working on something very similar (for the education business). Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680120.aspx) and [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2013/08/07/onenote-2013-com-api-xml-schema-onenote-2013-xsd.aspx).

Comment: @hector thankyou, ill take a look at this, are you creating a windows 8 application?

Answer (score 3):

From the question above I can see that you need onenote public APIs. Which comes as the first item in google search

http://dev.onenote.com/

Sample code is there on their github page
https://github.com/OneNoteDev